# How to I get cumulative monthly subtotals in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm using SSRS to create a report which shows a lot of transactions according to a trade date. I've made a group on the month and year called **'grpMonthYear'**. Inside that group I've made a subgroup on 'TradeDate'.

The groups and all work perfectly. I'm also generating monthly subtotals in the footer of the group 'grpMonthYear'.

But now I want the cumulative subtotals.

Example, if Jan'13 totaled up to $5,000.00 and transactions in Feb'13 totaled up to $7,000.00 So the monthly subtotal in Feb'13 should show me $12,000.00

I tried using

```
RunningValue(Fieldname,SUM,'grpMonthYear')
```

But it doesn't work.

Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the scope in the `RunningValue` function to one outside the current group, for example the table's DataSet itself.

So something like:

```
RunningValue(Fieldname,SUM,"DataSet")
```

Here's a simple example based on the following data:

[image]

I've created a simple report grouped by `grpMonthYear`:

[image]

The **Month Total** is just the sum in the current group scope.

The **Cumulative Total** expression is the following:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!tradePrice.Value, SUM , "Trades")
```

Where `Trades` is the **DataSet** name. This now gives the required results:

[image]

So hopefully this helps - just keep the ordering of all the elements of the table in mind as well as the specific parent scope to use if there are nested groups.

Comment: This works. As well as
    RunningValue(FieldName,SUM,Nothing)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed example.

Comment: You're welcome. Interesting that it works with a `Nothing` scope; I wouldn't have expected that - I guess it depends exactly where the TextBox is located in relation to everything else.